# Are clip-in human hair or synthetic hair extenions halal? (Hanafi opinion)

Tags: halal-haram, hanafi, hair

I have seen many people recently who have started wearing clip-in extensions for 1/2 hours for a family evening out. I am hanafi so I wanted to know the hanafi point of view for clip in hair extensions which you literally just clip in and you can take it out after 1/2 hours. I wanted to know what is the hanafi ruling on that? Some say its allowed and some say its not allowed but better to ask to be clear.

Answer (score -1):

Imam Bukhari and Imam Muslim have reported a narration of Sa'eed Bin Al-Musayyib:
"When the Mu'awiyah came to Medina for the last time, he delivered a sermon before us. He took out a tuft of hair and said: "I never thought that someone other than jews would do such a thing(i.e use false hair)." The prophet PBUH named such a thing as az-zur (false practice)"
(Parargaph from "Prohibited and Disliked Acts in Islam by Dr Shabbir Ahmed

From this and i have also heard from religous friends that wigs are haraam so my opinion is this would be the same thing.
I hope this is helpful :)